# Pandas get nested dict from Excel with multiple merged headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel sheet as shown below:

[image]

This is what I tried using `pandas`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_excel("temp.xlsx", headers=[5, 6], skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4], usecols="B:F")
>>> df
       Header 1    Unnamed: 2    Unnamed: 3      Header 2    Unnamed: 5
0  Sub header 1  Sub header 2  Sub header 3  Sub header 1  Sub header 2
1           111           NaN           131           211           221
2           112           122           132           NaN           NaN
3           NaN           NaN           NaN           213           223
```

And I got a nested dict structure from this using `df.to_dict()`:

```
>>> pprint(df.to_dict())
{'Header 1': {0: u'Sub header 1', 1: 111, 2: 112, 3: nan},
 'Header 2': {0: u'Sub header 1', 1: 211, 2: nan, 3: 213},
 'Unnamed: 2': {0: u'Sub header 2', 1: nan, 2: 122, 3: nan},
 'Unnamed: 3': {0: u'Sub header 3', 1: 131, 2: 132, 3: nan},
 'Unnamed: 5': {0: u'Sub header 2', 1: 221, 2: nan, 3: 223}}
```

As seen above, we have got `Unnamed: x` as key in the dict. How can I get rid of that and have the main header in its place?

Secondly, how can we get the columns that lie under the merged header?